# How to Index and make WHERE clause case insensitive?

Tags: postgresql

Have this table in **PostgreSQL 12**, no index

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    ...
    foods json NOT NULL
)
```

sample record:

```
foods:
{ 
    "fruits": [" 2 orange ", "1 apple in chocolate", " one pint of berry"],
    "meat": ["some beef", "ground beef", "chicken",...],
    "veg": ["cucumber"]
}
```

Need to select all records who satisfy:

1. fruits contains `orange`.
2. AND meat contains `beef` or `chicken`.

`select * from tbl where foods->> 'fruits' LIKE '%ORANGE%' and (foods->> 'meat' LIKE '%beef%' or foods->> 'meat' LIKE '%chicken%')`

Is it an optimized query? (I'm from RDBMS world)

How to index for faster response and not overkill, also how to make PostgreSQL case insensitive?

Comment: Would [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch.html) be an option?

Comment: You'd need to look at the EXPLAIN output for that query to see what PostgreSQL's query planner thinks of your indexes. I you want to index LIKE queries then look at [indexes using trigrams](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). If you want to index case insensitively, then apply the `lower` or `upper` function and look at [expression indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). If you need to get a little fancier then look at full text search as @tadman suggests.

Comment: @tadman although not right now but will keep it in mind.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the options, will study. I'm also considering turning JSON into JSONB if it helps in performance, not very sure how much work required on app side for this change.

Comment: `jsonb` should perform a lot better, AFAIK `json` is really just text that gets parsed all the time whereas `jsonb` is parsed only once and the parsed version is stored. Changing shouldn't affect the application side of things at all.

Answer (score 2):

This will make you unhappy.

You would need two trigram GIN indexes to speed this up:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING gin ((foods ->> 'fruits') gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING gin ((foods ->> 'meat') gin_trgm_ops);
```

These indexes can become large and will impact data modification performance.

Then you need to rewrite your query to use `ILIKE`.

Finally, the query might be slower than you want, because it will use three index scans and a (potentially expensive) bitmap heap scan.

But with a data structure like that and substring matches, you cannot do better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Absolutely correct, I didn't think of that. Fixed.